# Decrease list values by ratio in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a little programming issue that I'm trying to resolve in Clojure.

Say, I have a list with Integer values (they also include zeros). These values have a sum, which I want to decrease by a certain value. To get to this lower sum, I want to decrease the values in the list by ratio.

Say, I have the following list: [0, 10, 30, 40, 20, 0]. The sum is 100, and I want to decrease the sum to 90. I want to decrease the values by ratio, so the new list will be [0, 9, 27, 36, 18, 0].

However, this gets problematic when the numbers turn into fractions. When you round numbers (either with round, floor or ceil), you can end up with a sum that's off by 1 or 2. I can't seem to find an elegant solution. Everything I get consists of going through all the values once, and then going back to repair the offset. Any ideas?

**Edit**

To clarify the behaviour I want to see, the way it rounds doesn't really matter to me, as long as the sum is correct and the ratios of the numbers are approximately the same. I don't care care whether the total error is the smallest or that most are rounded down.

Additional requirements are that numbers are only allowed to stay equal or get lower, numbers should be >= 0, and the resulting list of numbers should be integers.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  You seem to want to take some ratio of the numbers of the input list such that the sum of the output list is equal to a given number.  As you point out, you don't always get integral results.  But you fail to mention what you expect in this case.  Also, please include what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can specify the function's requirements with clojure.spec. If we want the function to support integers w/arbitrary precision, sequences that sum to zero, empty sequences, etc., we could write this function spec:

```
(s/def ::natural-integer (s/and integer? (comp not neg?)))
(s/fdef dec-sum-int
  :args (s/and (s/cat :new-sum ::natural-integer
                      :nums (s/coll-of ::natural-integer))
               #(<= (:new-sum %) (apply +' (:nums %))))
  :ret  (s/coll-of ::natural-integer)
  :fn   (fn [{:keys [args ret]}]
          (and (= (count (:nums args)) (count ret))
               ;; each output <= corresponding input
               (every? true? (map <= ret (:nums args)))
               (or (empty? ret)
                   (= (:new-sum args) (apply + ret))))))
```

Then `st/check` the original answer below to see failing examples, or see example invocations with `s/exercise-fn`.

Here's a version that satisfies the spec for your updated requirements. Most of the complexity is to ensure each output <= input when adjusting for rounding error:

```
(defn dec-sum-int [new-sum nums]
  (let [sum   (apply +' nums)
        ratio (if (zero? sum) 1 (/ new-sum sum))
        nums' (map #(bigint (*' % ratio)) nums)
        err   (- new-sum (apply + nums'))]
    (loop [nums  nums
           nums' nums'
           out   []
           err   err]
      (cond
        (zero? err)
        (into out nums')

        (seq nums')
        (let [[num & more] nums
              [num' & more'] nums']
          (if (pos? num)
            (let [num'' (min num (+ num' err))]
              (recur more more'
                     (conj out num'')
                     (- err (- num'' num'))))
            (recur more more' (conj out num') err)))

        :else out))))

(st/summarize-results (st/check `dec-sum-int))
{:sym playground.so/dec-sum-int}
=> {:total 1, :check-passed 1}
```

**Original Answer**

Here's a function to multiply each number in a collection by a ratio to reach some desired sum:

```
(defn adjust-sum [new-sum nums]
  (let [sum (apply + nums)]
    (map #(* % (/ new-sum sum))
         nums)))

(adjust-sum 90 [0 10 30 40 20 0])
=> (0N 9N 27N 36N 18N 0N)
(map int *1)
=> (0 9 27 36 18 0)
```

For your example the results naturally come out as big integers. This is the only given example, but this problem lends itself well to property-based, generative testing. We can define properties that should hold for all examples and use test.check to test the function against many random examples we may not have imagined:

```
(tc/quick-check 10000
  (prop/for-all [new-sum gen/int
                 nums (->> (gen/vector gen/int)
                           ;; current approach fails for inputs that sum to zero
                           (gen/such-that #(not (zero? (apply + %)))))]
    (= new-sum (apply + (adjust-sum new-sum nums)))))
=> {:result true, :num-tests 10000, :seed 1552170880184}
```

*See updates above for handling examples with rounding error, or prior edits for handling negative numbers.*

Comment: Awesome, I love that you include a spec with it. There's just a little problem with adjust-sum-int. If the first value is a 0, then the adjustment will either make it a negative number (which is not allowed), or it will increase the value (which is also not allowed, all numbers should stay equal or go down). I guess it would be better to update the first non-zero value, or even better, the highest.

Comment: I saw it yeah, but I'm still undecided if I like this better or the answer that uses the Largest remainder method. It looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is way to solve it without going through the list a second time to fix the rounding. Here is one solution using [Largest Remainder Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method):

```clj
(defn adj-seq
  [input ratio rounding]
  (let [;;
        ;; function to apply ratio to a number
        ;;
        mul-ratio    (partial * ratio)
        ;;
        ;; function to apply ratio and rounding to a number
        ;;
        mul-ratio-r  (comp rounding mul-ratio)
        ;;
        ;; sort oirignal input with largest remainder first
        ;; then applies ratio and rounding to each number
        ;;
        rounded-list (->> input
                          (sort-by #(- (mul-ratio-r %)
                                       (mul-ratio %)))
                          (map mul-ratio-r))
        ;;
        ;; sum of original numbers
        ;;
        sum-input    (reduce + input)
        ;;
        ;; calculate the delta between the expected sum and sum of all rounded numbers
        ;;
        delta        (- (mul-ratio-r sum-input) (reduce + rounded-list))]

    ;;
    ;; distribute delta to the rounded numbers in largest remainder order
    ;;
    (->> rounded-list
         (reductions (fn [[remain _] e]
                       ;; increment number by 1 if remaining delta is >1
                       (if (pos? remain)
                         [(dec remain) (inc e)]
                         ;; otherwise returns the rounded number as is
                         [0 e]))
                     ;; delta is the initial value to feed to the reducing function
                     [delta])
         ;;
         ;; ignore the first output from the reducing function - which is the original delta
         ;;
         rest
         ;;
         ;; get the adjusted number: ratio + rounding + delta-adj
         ;;
         (map last))))
```

And a sample run:

```clj
(def input [0 10 30 40 20 0])
(def ratio 0.83)
(def rounding int)

(reduce + input)
;; => 100
(* ratio *1)
;; => 83.0
(adj-seq input ratio rounding)
;; => (25 17 8 33 0 0)
(reduce + *1)
;; => 83
```

Comment: Thank you, especially the link to the used method, that's information I needed (I couldn't find a place to start). Let me see if I can completely understand your code, sadly it's more complex than I hoped for, but I fear that's the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```clj
(defn scale-vector 
  "Given `s`, a sequence of numbers, and `t`, a target value for the sum of
  the sequence, return a sequence like `s` but with each number scaled 
  appropriately." 
  [s t]
  (let [ratio (/ (reduce + (filter number? s)) t)]
    (map #(if (number? %) (/ % ratio) %) s)))

(scale-vector [10 20 :foo 30 45.3 0 27/3] 21)
=> (1.837270341207349 3.674540682414698 :foo 5.511811023622047 8.32283464566929 0.0 1.6535433070866141)

(reduce + (filter number? (scale-vector [10 20 :foo 30 45.3 0 27/3] 21)))
=> 21.0
```

What's going on here:

1. We're assuming that `s` is a sequence of numbers; but it isn't necessarily an error if some element is not a number. Filtering for numbers allows us to cope gracefully is some elements are non-numeric; I've chosen to preserve non-numeric elements, but you could equally drop them.
2. I've done nothing special to exclude rational numbers from the output, and I can't see why you'd need to; but if you wanted to do that you could use `(map double [1 1/2 22/7]) => (1.0 0.5 3.142857142857143)`.
3. But idiomatically, in Clojure, a number is just a number. Any function that accepts numbers should accept numbers. Rational numbers - what you are referring to as 'fractions' - are just numbers like any other numbers. Don't worry about them.

Comment: Thank you! I like that you check for non-numbers! However, I want the resulting list to consist of integers. I've updated the original question to clarify this.

Comment: Ah! then you want to map something which converts to integer over the results. e.g. `(map int '(22/7 3.14 0.001))`. Of course, you could equally use `(map #(int (Math/ceil %)) result)`. There isn't a convenient `Math/round`, but if that's what you need use `(map #(int (+ 0.5 %)) result)`.

Comment: Note also a gotcha: the basic `+ - *` and `/` functions in Clojure work only for 64 bit values. If the result overflows a 64 bit value you get an exception, which is just silly. What isn't well documented is that there are alternative functions `+'`, `-'`, `*'` and`/'` which handle values exceeding 64 bits correctly. The performance penalty for doing this is extremely small and I would recommend using the arbitrary precision versions everywhere except in code where performance needs to be optimised.

Comment: Yes, except that in the conversion to integers, the rounding will probably cause the total sum to be incorrect.